# How to get Android Studio to return value from a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: android, sql-server, stored-procedures

How to get Android Studio to return value from a SQL Server stored procedure? Help me I need this.

I want get `@ID` value

My code

```
connect2 = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
stmt2 = connect2.prepareStatement("EXEC InsertSatislar '"+MusteriID+"','"+date+"','"+time+"','"+paketno+"','"+persid+"','"+persid+"','"+toptutar+"','"+alinan+",'"+kalan+"','"+iskonto+"','"+aciklama+"','"+BayiID+"','"+BayiID+"','"+m+"','"+1+"','"+0+"'");

stmt2.executeUpdate();
```

My procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertSatislar]
    @ID INT OUT,
    @musteriID INT,
    @tarih DATE,
    @saat NVARCHAR(12),
    @paketNo INT,
    @teslimEdenPersonelID INT,
    @kullaniciID INT,
    @toplamTutar FLOAT,
    @alinan FLOAT,
    @kalan FLOAT,
    @iskonto FLOAT,
    @aciklama NVARCHAR(250),
    @bayiID INT,
    @nedenBayiID INT,
    @durum NVARCHAR(4),
    @satisSekliID INT,
    @MenuID INT
AS
    INSERT INTO Satislar(MusteriID, Tarih, Saat, PaketNo, TeslimEdenPersonelID, TeslimAlanPersonelID, ToplamTutar, Alinan, Kalan, Iskonto, Aciklama, SatisMi, BayiID, NerdenBayiID, Durum,SatisSekliID,MenuID,FaturaID) 
    VALUES (@musteriID, @tarih, @saat, @paketNo, @teslimedenPersonelID, @kullaniciID, @toplamTutar, @alinan, @kalan, @iskonto, @aciklama, 'True', @bayiID, @nedenBayiID, @durum,@satisSekliID,@MenuID,0) select @ID=@@identity

    RETURN
```

I want get `@ID`

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: If you use prepareStatement, why don't you use parameter placeholders instead of string concatenation?

Comment: Laposhasu Acsa how to use ?

Comment: Can you show example

Answer (score 0):

this works well for me

```
if (conn != null) {
                String qryInsereNovo = "INSERT INTO #TABLE#(NAME) VALUES('" + edtUserName.getText() + "')";
                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(qryInsereNovo, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();

                if (affectedRows == 0) {
                    throw new SQLException("Cadastro de nova pessoa falhou. Tente novamente!");
                }

                try (ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        long getIdInsert;
                        getIdInsert = rs.getLong(1);
                 }
                } finally {
                    conn.close();
                }
```

This returns the `@id`

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(qryInsereNovo, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```